# How do I catch CommunicationsException when there is an error connecting with server?

Tags: java

I have a database program in Java and MySQL. I want to display an error message to the user if there is an error connecting with the server, my program gives this exception when local server is turned off:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

I've tried a try-catch but it doesn't catch it and display the error message, any ideas?

```
package javadatabaseprogram;

import java.sql.*;

public class JavaDatabaseProgram {
static private Connection c;
public static Connection getCon() throws Exception {

try{        
    if (c == null){
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/std_registry", "root", "");
    }
return c;
}

catch(Exception e){
            DialogBox db = new DialogBox();
            db.setVisible(true);
            db.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            db.jTextField1.setText("Cannot connect to server!");
}
    return null;
}
   public static void setData(String s) throws Exception{
   JavaDatabaseProgram.getCon().createStatement().executeUpdate(s);
}

public static ResultSet getData(String sq) throws Exception{
    return JavaDatabaseProgram.getCon().createStatement().executeQuery(sq);
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe c is not null so then you don't cache error :)

Comment: What is `DialogBox` ? Maybe the GUI isnt responsing. What if you log `Exception` to stderr ?

Comment: DialogBox is a Jframe i custom designed. I tried by not setting c to null.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the simple version below without static Connection with Exception.

For example:

```
public class MyDAO {
    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1";
    private static final String PORT = "3306";
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASS = "root";
    private static final int MAX_ACTIVE = 10;
    private static final int MAX_IDLE = 5;
    private static final int INITIAL_SIZE = 5;

    private String database = "your_db_";
    private Connection conn = null;
    private Statement stmt = null;

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public boolean connect() {
      try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL+":"+PORT, USER, PASS);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "CREATE DATABASE " + database;
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        }
       //
       try {
           BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

           dataSource.setDriverClassName(JDBC_DRIVER);
           dataSource.setUsername("root");
           dataSource.setPassword("root");

           dataSource.setUrl(URL+":"+PORT+ "/" + database);
           dataSource.setMaxActive(MAX_ACTIVE);
           dataSource.setMaxIdle(MAX_IDLE);
           dataSource.setInitialSize(INITIAL_SIZE);
           jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(){
        return jdbcTemplate;
    };
}
```

Your code:
   without ... static Connection getCon() throws Exception {

```
DialogBox db = new DialogBox();
db.setVisible(true);
db.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
MyDAO dao = new MyDAO();
if (dao.connect()) {
    db.jTextField1.setText("Connect to server!");
} else {
    db.jTextField1.setText("Cannot connect to server check log!");
}
```

Comment: can it be done using the getCon() method? bcuz a lot of things rely on that method.